# Error in my MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql

Trying some queries on the database, but I have a problem. Can somebody help me with proper query?

This is what I need

```
SELECT 
    IdNews, Caption, NewsText, NumberOfViews, NumberOfComments,
    PublishDate, CoinValue, category.IdNewsCategory,  
    NewsCategory, country.IdCountry, CountryName, news.IdUser, 
    FirstName, LastName, Picture, DateTimeUpCoin 
FROM 
    news 
INNER JOIN 
    category ON category.IdNewsCategory = news.IdNewsCategory 
INNER JOIN 
    country ON news.IdCountry = country.IdCountry
INNER JOIN 
    user ON user.IdUser = news.IdUser
WHERE 
    news.IdCountry = 1
LIMIT 0, 10
ORDER BY 
    NumberOfViews DESC
```

Comment: Try with `WHERE news.IdCountry =1`

Comment: I just edited my question, can you help me, thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written wrong query for Order by.

In query, `LIMIT` comes always last.

You need to write corrected query as per below :

```
SELECT
    IdNews,Caption,NewsText,NumberOfViews,NumberOfComments,
    PublishDate,CoinValue,category.IdNewsCategory,
    NewsCategory,country.IdCountry,CountryName,news.IdUser,
    FirstName, LastName,Picture, DateTimeUpCoin 
FROM news 
INNER JOIN category ON category.IdNewsCategory = news.IdNewsCategory 
INNER JOIN country ON news.IdCountry = country.IdCountry
INNER JOIN user ON user.IdUser = news.IdUser
WHERE news.IdCountry = 1
ORDER BY NumberOfViews DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`IdCountry` column is present in both the tables `news` and `country`. That's why it is showing error. Prepend table name before `IdCountry` in `where` clause. Put `ORDER BY` before `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT IdNews,Caption,NewsText,NumberOfViews,NumberOfComments,PublishDate,CoinValue,category.IdNewsCategory, NewsCategory,country.IdCountry,CountryName,news.IdUser,FirstName, LastName,Picture, DateTimeUpCoin 
    FROM news 
    INNER JOIN category ON category.IdNewsCategory = news.IdNewsCategory 
    INNER JOIN country ON news.IdCountry = country.IdCountry
    INNER JOIN user ON user.IdUser = news.IdUser
    WHERE news.IdCountry =1
    ORDER BY NumberOfViews DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: I also have order by?

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Try with ORDER BY news.NumberOfViews DESC

Comment: put order by before limit